# Format String to right, left and centre justify in C#

Tags: c#, string-formatting, .net-6.0

I am working on .NET 6.0 application and need to apply right, centre and left justify string. The objective is apply formatting to string and then write string stream to text file.

Each of string are with space i.e. batchIdTag is must of be 25 character so I have added spaces based on actual string length to make total of 25 character string.

In following code I need to justify `amountTag` to right and `InterfaceTag` in Centre but unable to do so?

```
 public static void JustifyTxt()
    {
        try
        {
            string batchIdHeader = "BatchId                 ";
            string interfaceHeader = "Interface               ";
            string voucherTypeHeader = "VoucherType             ";
            string amountHeader = "Amount             ";
            string voucherNoHeader = "VoucherNo      ";

            string batchIdTag = "AIMGL07_220428           ";
            string interfaceTag = "XA                       ";
            string voucherTypeTag = "GL                       ";
            string amountTag = "1000                ";
            string voucherNoTag = "123238         ";


            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"{batchIdHeader}|{interfaceHeader}|{voucherTypeHeader}|{amountHeader}|{voucherNoHeader}");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

            var formatedTag = String.Format("{0,0}{1,0}{2,0}{3,3}{4,0} ", batchIdTag, interfaceTag,voucherTypeTag,amountTag,voucherNoHeader);

            Console.WriteLine(formatedTag);
            

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        
    }
```

[image]

`Answer`

```
     public static void JustifyTxtCentre()
    {
        string tag = "AIMGL07_220428";

        int tagLen = tag.Length;
        int tagMaxWidth = 25;

        int tagLenDifference = tagMaxWidth - tag.Length;

        int totalPaddingToAdd = tagLenDifference > 0? tagLenDifference : checked(-tagLenDifference);

        int distributePaddings = totalPaddingToAdd / 2;

        int leftPaddings = distributePaddings;
        int rightPaddings = distributePaddings;

        var processedTag = new string(' ', leftPaddings) + tag + new string(' ', rightPaddings);

        if(processedTag.Length == (tagMaxWidth - 1))
        {
            processedTag = processedTag + new string(' ', 1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show the expected string?

Comment: [Padding Strings in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding)

Comment: Console output [Composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting)

Comment: Frist remove the manual padding from the strings and in `{3,3}` second `3` should be the size of the whole "column".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string batchIdHeader ="BatchId";
string interfaceHeader ="Interface";
string voucherTypeHeader ="VoucherType";
string amountHeader ="Amount";
string voucherNoHeader ="VoucherNo";

string batchIdTag ="AIMGL07_220428";
string interfaceTag ="XA";
string voucherTypeTag ="GL";
string amountTag ="1000";
string voucherNoTag ="123238";

const int pad = 15;
Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 5*pad + 4)); // 5 columns + (5-1) spacers
Console.WriteLine($"{batchIdHeader,-pad}|{Centred(pad, interfaceHeader),-pad}|{voucherTypeHeader,-pad}|{amountHeader,pad}|{voucherNoHeader,-pad}");
Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 5*pad + 4));

Console.WriteLine($"{batchIdTag,-pad}|{Centred(pad, interfaceTag),-pad}|{voucherTypeTag,-pad}|{amountTag,pad}|{voucherNoTag,-pad}");

static string Centred( int total, string s) => s.PadLeft((total - s.Length) / 2 + s.Length);
```

prints

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BatchId        |   Interface   |VoucherType    |         Amount|VoucherNo      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AIMGL07_220428 |      XA       |GL             |           1000|123238
```

If pad needs to be dynamic I would you can use `PadLeft` and `PadRight` instead '`,pad}`':

```
int w = 15;
Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 5*w + 4));
Console.WriteLine($"{Left(batchIdHeader,w)}|{Centred(interfaceHeader, w)}|{Left(voucherTypeHeader, w)}|{Right(amountHeader,w)}|{Left(voucherNoHeader,w)}");
Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 5*w + 4));

Console.WriteLine($"{Left(batchIdTag,w)}|{Centred(interfaceTag, w)}|{Left(voucherTypeTag, w)}|{Right(amountTag,w)}|{Left(voucherNoTag,w)}");

static string Centred(string s, int total) => s.PadLeft((total - s.Length) / 2 + s.Length).PadRight(total);
static string Left(string s, int total) => s.PadRight(total);
static string Right(string s, int total) => s.PadLeft(total);
```

Comment: OP - _" and InterfaceTag in Centre"_

Comment: Working on it :)

Comment: Also I would say OP wants `24` at some columns based on data and output.

Comment: 25 is too much for stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly:

1. You may pad specific number of empty spaces to align right (String.PadRight)
2. You may use /t to add tab after a string to give space before other string. (or String.PadLeft)